# Get the result of a WMIC command and store it in a variable

Tags: batch-file, scripting, wmic

I have seen some batch scripts working that way, including all around stackoverflow.

My question is simple: Why the MEM part isn't working?

```
@echo OFF

SET CPU="$CPU"

echo CPU: %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory') DO set MEM=%%i

echo MEM: %MEM%
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working"! I think you ran into the problem derived from Unicode-to-ANSI conversion of the `wmic` output by `for /F` which leaves orphaned carriage-return characters that disturbs proper text parsing; take a look at this post for a solution: [Parsing the output of wmic in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19351263).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple. `wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory` outputs three lines of text:

```
TotalPhysicalMemory
12867309568
<blank line>
```

So your for-loop does three iteration. In the first one `MEM` is set to `TotalPhysicalMemory`, in the second one it's set to `12867309568` and finally it becomes . So your output is empty.

This is quite ugly but will solve your problem:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET CPU="$CPU"
echo CPU: %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
FOR /F "delims= skip=1" %%i IN ('wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory') DO (
    set MEM=%%i
    goto STOP

)
:STOP
echo MEM: !MEM!
```

`skip=1` will ignore `TotalPhysicalMemory` and `goto STOP` will break the loop after the first iteration.

Comment: Actually, the command was edited to simplify the question. The intention was: 

'wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory | findstr -v "Total"'

And the result of the script for my (tested in 4 servers):

G:\>get_numphycpu.bat
CPU: 6
MEM:

Comment: By the way, thank you for the answer. It worked, and I understood why :)

Comment: @DavidLago you can also check my answer with formatting the output of WMIC with `For / Do` loop

Comment: The third line is definitely *not* empty as such would be skipped be `for /F`, but that line contains an orphaned carriage-return character; also the other two lines may have carriage-return characters appended; the *only reliable method* of getting rid of these characters without a temporary file is to use *two nested `for /F` loops*, like illustrated in these posts: [Text garble in batch script for wmic command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25604222), [For /F with wmic unwanted output](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34695095) and [Hackoo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39269615) here.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like that with formatting the output of `WMIC` with `For / Do` loop like that :

```
@echo off
Call :GetTotalPhysicalMemory
echo TotalPhysicalMemory = %MEM% & pause
exit
::***********************************************
:GetTotalPhysicalMemory
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('
    wmic computersystem get TotalPhysicalMemory /value
') do for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
    Set "MEM=%%b" 
)
exit /b
::***********************************************
```